# Homotopy in the two-point discrete space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology, and let $c_0, c_1: D^2 \to X$ be the constant maps at $0$ and $1$ respectively. Is $c_0$ homotopic to $c_1$?

My intuition says no, because if $h:D^2 \times I \to X$ were a homotopy between them, then in particular $p: I \to X, \ \ i \mapsto h(\theta, i)$ (where $\theta$ is the center of $D^2$) would be the a (continuous) path from $0$ to $1$ in $X$, which is not possible since $I$ is connected. But somehow I am not sure of the validity of this argument.

So my question is, first of all is this argument valid, and if not, what is a valid argument proving or disproving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D^2 \times I$ is connected, so its image under a continuous map is connected. If $D^2 \times \{0\} \mapsto 0$, then $D^2 \times I \mapsto 0$. There is no homotopy between the two constant maps. (More generally, two maps from a connected space whose images lie in different connected components of the codomain cannot be homotopic).

This is precisely your argument.